# Rails cross reference another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model of `department` that has many `members`.  Members are saved with department attributes which save the department's ID number.  When I want to see the department I only see the number for the department.  How can I use the ID number of the department to reference the department's string saved in the department model?

Comment: Department.find(<insert your department id here>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
member = Member.first
department = Department.find(member.department_id)
```

But, since there is a relation established between two models, you could simply do the following (I assume you have `belongs_to: :department` in `Member` model):

```
member.department # will return the Department object
```